# Remote in from Europe

Tags: wireless-networking

I am going on to Spain for three weeks, during my stay there I have responsibilities I will have to remote to my computer at the office for. Is this possible? Also can I remote in from public internet?
I have no contacts in Spain that would be able to answer this question.
Can you help answer?
Thank you

Comment: Please ask your IT team how to remote into your machine and whether there are restrictions (either technical or policy) that would prevent you accessing from Spain.

Answer (score 0):

You can. There's the option to install a general use remote software like Teamviewer, let it run at the location you require and you will be able to connect there at any time from anywhere. A more professional approach is a certificate-based VPN, but that may harder to setup by yourself.

The solutions above will work as long as there is no specific software or security policy to intentionally deny access to this kind of software.

Comment: Its worth being aware that Teamviewer was recently compromised. Using an officially supported VPN and remote access from wherever the office is is probably a good idea

Comment: Yes, there were hacked accounts. Any such software can be compromised at a point. Having the latest version and setting a good password are good practices. You don't even need to setup an account.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I hope to have no glitches. Thank you this makes me feel a little more at ease.

Comment: "general use remote software"? Teamviewer? What is this? I've never heard of this

Comment: Basically, it's a software that installs on both your computer and the target computers you want to access and then you can connect to any of the computers that have the software installed and you know the access user/password for. Most of them establish pretty secure tunnels, so security should be fine.